# iam new to laravel 8 Iam creating Routes and they generate an error

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

am creating route in laravel-8 only one route is working and the others are not why
Routes problem

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('dashboard');
});
```

only the '/' the first route working and the other 2 which are below are not working.  when want to access on teh screen shows that
404 NOT FOUND.
please some one help me.

```
Route::get('/allProducts', function() {
 
    return "view('products');";
});


Route::get('contact',function(){

    return "hello ";
});
```

Comment: `return "view('products');";` would return a string, is that intended? Do the routes show up in `php artisan route:list`?

Comment: the issue may be of web-server you use, - what is that server?

Comment: sounds like url rewriting / pretty urls isn't setup correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, make sure your URL is correct. According to Laravel 8 [documents](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#sharing-data-with-all-views), you have to display it this way. If this problem persists, check your web server configuration.

```
Route::get('/allProducts', function () {
    return view('dashboard');
});
```

To see which routes are set up run the following form command line.

```
php artisan route:list
```

start a development server by running the following in your command line

```
localhost:8000/allProducts
```

Comment: No this is not working even this route also.  ```Route::get('user/{id}', function ($id) {
    return 'User '.$id;
});```

Comment: Check your web server configuration @BILALHUSSAIN